# How to eliminate error "TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV not supported" from website's SSL testing results

Tags: ssl, nginx

Any idea how to resolve this issue and avoid this alert? I am getting it under Qualys SSL Labs website's SSL test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade your server software (server and SSL libraries) to a version supporting this fairly new option.

Comment: Thank you @Steffen Ullrich, that solved the issue.